# Inject javascript function into WebView on page load

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to inject a global JavaScript function into a webview before the page loads. I have a function called `testJS` that I am injecting in. In my WebViewClient I am doing the following

```
private String getJS() {
    return "javascript:function testJS() { return { test: 'Hello World' };}";
}

 @Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    view.loadUrl(getJS());
}
```

When I inspect the page, `window.testJS` is undefined.

If I do the following, `window.testJS` has the correct function in the webview but it is not loaded early enough so does not work correctly.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(getJS());
}
```

In iOS I could do the equivalent with injecting a script `atDocumentStart` and it works the way I expect it to.

```
let userScript = WKUserScript(
        source: scriptContent!,
        injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart,
        forMainFrameOnly: false)
contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
```

Is there another way I can achieve this in an android WebView? It works onPageFinished but not onPageStarted.

Answer (score -4):

First try to allow javascript as a setting feature:

```
WebSettings webSettings = yourWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Then:

```
yourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(){
       @JavascriptInterface
       public void test(){
           Log.d("JS", "test");
            }
   },"Android");
yourWebview.loadUrl("javascript:functionName(\"" + argument + "\")");
```

Refer to these questions:

[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

[Call javascript function in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023991/call-javascript-function-in-android-webview)

Comment: It is enabled. That is not the issue. The issue is the JavaScript is not loaded correctly from onPageStarted.

Comment: Where does my JavaScript go? What is the point of the interface if you are just loading a javascript function anyways

Comment: still not what I am asking. The question is about loading JavaScript before the page loads. I am able to load JS in a WebView fine but I need it before the actual webpage is rendered. I need a JS function injected that is called via the page.