# closing webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using Twitter4j but I need to authenticate a user with oAuth. The user needs to get a pin and input it into the app. When I load a webview with the url and the user accept's to give the app privileges, they receive a pin. How would they close the webview in order to input the pin. I cant close the webview in the emulator. Below is the method in the Async class where the webview is shown after the url is retrieved.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String url) {

        WebView webview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadUrl(url);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could

- instead use another dedicated activity with mainly a webview [potentially also with 'done' button]. You could start that activity from your `onPostExecute` with intent, and then you will go back when user is done with it, or you could start that webview activity [for result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)
- Another option is to replace your webview when you are done with another view, for example by calling `setContentView` with another layout. I never did this myself, and not sure it will work easily, but I found that some people recommend using [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) for similar effect.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "close" a WebView. What you could do is hide it. Maybe this solution will shed some light - [Hide WebView until JavaScript is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342100/android-hide-webview-until-javascript-is-done)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
webview.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `finish()` from anywhere inside the Activity class

Answer (score 1):

Add a close button and on its click set:

```java
webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
webview.loadUrl("");
```

You can then reduce the height width of the web view to minimum.